# How to create specific, automated bandwidth/network traffic for experiment..?

Tags: shell, networking, scripting, network-traffic

So for my job I need to do an experiment..

The essence and part where I get stuck at now is how to create a specific amount of bandwidth/network traffic. From either Linux or windows, (I have both a Kali and Win10 VM). To a target Win10 pc which monitors it's resources to see the reaction to the traffic.

Preferably 3 different amounts of traffic with a certain time between them, like a scripted sleep timer or something..

So like the following:

```
Sleep 180 seconds
Send 10mbps for 120 seconds
Sleep 180 seconds
Send 25mbps for 120 seconds
Sleep 180 seconds
Send 50mbps for 120 seconds
Exit
```

Now this shouldn't be as hard as I'm thinking of it to be right?

Any pointers on some software or scripts I could use for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From linux shell `cat /dev/urandom | telnet hostname` ? timeout the execution with, well,  `timeout` utility.

Comment: Do you really mean to send 50mb per second, at constant speed 120 times ? There is no easy way to force transmission at a specific rate. You can send 50mb, and force a delay if this completed within a specific time (until next second) - effectively imposing rate limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iperf3](https://iperf.fr/iperf-doc.php), a tool for stress testing and measuring network performance, along with basic bash scripting to accomplish this.  iperf3 is cross-platform, so it is supported on both Kali Linux and Win 10.

On Kali Linux, I used the system package manager to install it:

```
apt install iperf3
```

On Windows, I downloaded the 64 bit binary from the [iperf3 download site](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php#windows).
Then used the following command to start an iperf3 server:

```
iperf3 -s
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

This will start the server listening on a particular port as shown above.  Then on my Kali Linux instance, I use iperf3 again as a client to connect to the server:

```
iperf3 -c <address-of-server> -b 25M -t 7
[  5] local XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 42650 connected to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  2.98 MBytes  25.0 Mbits/sec    0    133 KBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  3.00 MBytes  25.2 Mbits/sec    0    133 KBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  3.00 MBytes  25.2 Mbits/sec    0    133 KBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  3.00 MBytes  25.2 Mbits/sec    0    133 KBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  3.00 MBytes  25.2 Mbits/sec    0    133 KBytes       
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  3.00 MBytes  25.2 Mbits/sec    2    133 KBytes       
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  3.00 MBytes  25.2 Mbits/sec    1    133 KBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-7.00   sec  21.0 MBytes  25.1 Mbits/sec    3             sender
[  5]   0.00-7.00   sec  21.0 MBytes  25.1 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

The -b option allows me to specify the bit rate, in the example above 25 Mbits/sec and the -t option allows specifying how long it should run, in this case 7 seconds.

You can easily use this tool in a script to achieve the behavior you want, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Sleeping for 180 seconds"
sleep 180
echo "Stress testing at 10Mb/s for 120 seconds"
iperf3 -c mywinserver.local -b 10M -t 120
echo "Sleeping for 180 seconds"
sleep 180
echo "Stress testing at 25Mb/s for 120 seconds"
iperf3 -c mywinserver.local -b 25M -t 120
echo "Sleeping for 180 seconds"
sleep 180
echo "Stress testing at 50Mb/s for 120 seconds"
iperf3 -c mywinserver.local -b 50M -t 120
```